# Can we collide two Nano Spacecraft moving at 20% speed of light?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, moments

[Nano spacecrafts](https://newatlas.com/self-healing-nano-spacecraft-nasa-kaist/46890/) are gram level silicon chips that will be accelerated to 20% of the speed of light to reach Alpha Centauri in 20 years.

I wonder if we can break the weight limitation by shooting multiple spacecraft and connecting them after the acceleration. To test this idea, I need your help with calculating the numbers. Let's assume that we want to connect two spacecraft, $A$ and $B$.

- $A$ is accelerated before $B$.
- $B$ is accelerated to a speed slightly bigger than $A$
- it takes $t$ days for $B$ to catch up $A$

As $B$ will get closer to $A$ it will have better precision aligning on $A$ collision path, but it will also require more energy to navigate $B$

Please calculate what precision is needed to collide with $A$ and what maneuvering speed $B$ needs to do it.

This question doesn't contain all the details for making this calculation. I am looking for a realistic example to understand if such a mission is even possible, so please feel the gaps with realistic assumptions about the problem.

Comment: Many existing spacecraft could get through the gaps...

Comment: @SolarMike, I don't think there are many existing spacecraft with gram level weight. Could you please expand on what do you mean?